# Graphics drivers could not find compatible graphics hardware

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card

I have a desktop with Asus P5KPS/EPU motherboard and Nvidia GF 9600 GT Graphic Adapter. I just set up new windows 7.

My problem is that I cannot find a good dirver for my Graphic Adapter. I've downloaded driver from Nvidia.com which say support my GF 9600 GT, but when I installed it, it said This graphics drivers could not find compatible graphics hardware. I go into safe mode, uninstall Standard Graphics Adapter that auto installed then install my Nvidia driver, still not work. Anyone can show me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Is it 32bit of windows or 64 bit?

Comment: I found this link for [asus nvidia graphic card](http://www.asus.com/Graphics_Cards/NVIDIA_Series/EN9600GTHTDI512M/#download) download the vga for your motherboard and install them.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the graphic drivers are not provided by the brand which they belong for a motherboard with which graphic card come along, so you have to take a look on the motherboard site too. Also try to update your bios.

You can download the [Asus Graphic Driver](http://www.asus.com/Graphics_Cards/NVIDIA_Series/EN9600GTHTDI512M/#download) for Nvidia just select your OS there. There is also a bios update and of course you can try it if the drivers don't install again after downloading from here. There are three versions of VGA and I'll recommend you to download the first one as its the last updated driver for this card.

Before installing drivers make sure you have uninstalled all old drivers and then reinstall the setup through it.

Also you can check through the [Nvidia site](http://www.geforce.com/drivers) and you can use **Auto Detect Your GPU** feature. Here are [FAQ](http://www.geforce.com/drivers/faq) about GPU.

Comment: I use Automatic Driver Detection and it say "NVIDIA Products Not Found
We could not find any NVIDIA products within your system. Please try again or use the manual search." But I am sure there is only one Graphic Card attach to my motherboard and it is NVIDIA.

Comment: Have you tried to download the driver from the motherboard site which I have mention in my answer. Download that driver and then tell me what happens.

Comment: Yes, I downloaded the driver that you mentioned and It still not work. I followed this post http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=222904 and finally I be able to install the driver. However after install the driver, my computer freeze after it loads its taskbar and sometime its stuck at welcome screen. I boot into safe mode then uninstall the driver and restart and my computer work  ok. In device manager, driver of my graphic adapter is Standard VGA Graphic Adapter. I want to replace it with a proper driver and I cannot. I can but after install, my computer freeze.

Comment: What is the hardware ID shown in Device Manager for your VGA Graphic Adapter (on the Details tab)?  It should be something like `PCI\VEN_0x10DE&DEV_0x0642`.

Comment: Ben is on the right track here. If a 9600GT isn't being detected by the nVidia graphics driver package the most likely culprit is the device BIOS isn't communicating a relevant piece of data to the system BIOS. Most likely the hardware ID, but it could be another entry.  Install SiSoft Sandra and/or GPUid and use the information tools to confirm the info matches what you see in Windows.  Both those programs are nice because they poll the hardware directly.

Answer (score 0):

If there are any other video drivers on the hard drive, such as intel's uninstall them. in device manager where you would find the graphics displays, see if the graphics card is actually functioning properly. Also you may want to select, in the bios, that PCI is the primary display and you may also want to disable integrated graphics should there be any issues. Doing an advanced search on NVIDIA's website of your [cards drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) should ensure you have the latest/best drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Some drivers may be tricky to get accepted in specific cases.

[Have a go at these drivers](http://www.guru3d.com/files_details/geforce_310_70_whql_driver_download.html)